# Can't figure out relationships between two models

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm writing a CMS plugin, in which I have two basic models -- `Category` and `Entry`. Each of this model is related to another through `has_and_belongs_to_many` relationship. But I can't figure out, how should I point this out in their controllers and routes. For example, I need to render all of entries belongning to certain category, within `categories#show` action. 
Here are the models:

```
class Entry < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :categories
end

class Category < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :entries
end
```

This is my `categories_controller`:

```
def show
  @category = Category.find(params[:id])
  @entries = @category.entries.all
end
```

and within my `show.html.erb` template:

```
<% @entries.each do |entry| %>
  <%= link_to entry.title, entry_path(entry) %>
<% end %>
```

and my routes:

```
resources :categories do
  scope '/:content_class' do
    resources :entries
  end
end
```

But every time I get an error, that there's no `categories_entries` relationship in the database. What am I doing wrong?

Here is a [link to the whole project](https://github.com/multifloracms/multiflora/tree/development)

Comment: Have you migrated your database?

Comment: I use STI, once my plugin is installed, there's no need in further migrations

Comment: Why do you have two tables for the two models then?

Comment: @Dr.Nefario they are two basic models in the plugin, other models in the project would inherit from them

Answer (score 1):

After I looked at the github repository you provided, I think you need to have a cross-reference table to make the association work.

The reason for this is that there should be a way to distinguish which records of one table have connection with which of the other table. In the case of `one-to-many` relationship like `has_one` or `belongs_to` this is achieved by recording the `id` of one of the models in the table of the other model. Since you need more than one `id` recorded in each of the records in both tables, this is only possible with a separate table.

Try making such a table with only two fields: `category_id` and `entry_id`, with a migration similar to this snippet:

```
class CreateCategoryEntryJoinTable < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :categories_entries, id: false do |t|
      t.integer :category_id
      t.integer :entry_id
    end
  end
end
```

You could read more from here: http://apidock.com/rails/v4.2.1/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods/has_and_belongs_to_many

Comment: I've done exactly as you told, but there's still the same error :( may be there's something I've done wrong in my controllers?

Comment: @AlexNikolaev94 Check if the names of the table and the fields in the table are correct. If they are did you execute the migration? I don't see problems with your controllers and the message doesn't imply anything but the absence of this table...

Answer (score 0):

A `has_and_belongs_to_many` association requires a join-table which you haven't created. Please see [this guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-and-belongs-to-many-association) for more information.